# How to access values passed from ant script to shell script

Tags: ant

We have a shell script which we invoke it from an ant script. We need to pass input to shell script from ant script. It can be done as follows

```
<target name="help">
  <exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="Hello"/>
    <arg value="Welcome"/>
    <arg value="World"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

But We are not able to figure out how to access the values passed from ant script in shell script. Could anyone please suggest me with the right information.Thanks.

Comment: Just like any other script variables? E.g. `%1`, `%2` and so on - I assume you use Windows batch scripts.

Comment: Iam on Linux Machine and it is a sh file.

Comment: Then do it like `$1`, `$2` and so on.

Comment: I followed the way you suggested but iam not able to access the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use properties as input, something like :

```
<project>
 <property name="foobar" location="C:/foobar" />
 <property name="foo" value="bar" />

 <exec executable="cmd">
   <arg value="/c" />
   <env key="PATH" path="${env.PATH};${foobar}/bin" />
   <arg value="set" />
 </exec>

 <exec executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c" />
  <arg value="echo" />
  <arg value="${foo}" />
 </exec>
</project>
```

You have to use `/c` as first arg value.
When calling a batfile which expects %1 ... %9 as input, first arg is `<arg value=/c">`,
second arg `<arg value="yourbatfile.bat/>`.
The following args  `<arg value=.../>` would be %1 and so on, f.e. :

foobar.bat

```
@echo off
echo First argument %1
echo Second argument %2
```

build.xml

```
<project>

<exec dir="dir="path/to/batfile" executable="cmd">
 <arg value="/c"/>
 <arg value="foobar.bat"/>
 <arg value="foo"/>
 <arg value="bar"/>
</exec>

</project>
```

output

```
[exec] First argument foo
[exec] Second argument bar
```

Example for calling a shellscript, first arg has to be `<arg value="/path/to/shellscript.sh"/>`, the following args `<arg value="..."/>` will be $1 ...

foobar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "\$# = $#"
echo "\$0 = $0"
echo "\$1 = $1"
echo "\$2 = $2"
```

build.xml

```
<project>
 <exec executable="/bin/bash">
  <arg value="/path/to/foobar.sh"/>
  <arg value="foo"/>
  <arg value="bar"/>
 </exec>
</project>
```

Comment: Iam not using a bat file iam using an sh file. Is it going to have any impact?Do I have to change anything from what you have suggested?

Comment: Iam not able to clearly understand your example. Iam pasting my code below please have a look

<exec executable="status.sh" outputproperty="output.value" resultproperty="exec.result" failonerror="false">
                 <arg value="${mbean.name}" />
                        <arg value="55011" />
               </exec>

Comment: Sorry for reposting please find the code below

build.xml
<exec executable="status.sh" outputproperty="output.value" resultproperty="exec.result" failonerror="false">
                        <arg value="55011" />
 </exec>

status.sh
PORT= $1

Comment: @Sunayana Look at the example from Rebse. It's `<exec executable="/bin/bash">`, not `<exec executable="status.sh" ...>`. To have Bash execute `status.sh`, insert `<arg value="status.sh"/>` under `<exec>`.

Comment: @Chad I need to also specify the location of the status.sh file ,so where do i do it?

Comment: @Sunayana: `<arg value="/full/path/to/status.sh"/>`